# I have an equation I need to prove but I don't really have an idea how to:

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

$$
\left||y|\,x^2-|b|\,a^2\right| \leq 2(|x-a|+|y-b|), \quad\forall x,y,a,b \in(-1,1)
$$
It is part of a much longer proof and I'm not entirely sure that it is necessary (or reasonable).

Comment: Please explain your notation. What is $*$?

Comment: oh this is my first question so i just typed times on the keyboard. Is the standart notation $\dot$ or what do you use?

Comment: Formatting tips are [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is not an equation, it's an inequality. Since it should be true $\forall x,y,a,b \in(-1,1)$, you cannot "solve" it. As you say you have to prove it is true.

Comment: My bad im from germany so im not 100% used to the english words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By triangle and reverse-triangle inequalities:
$$\left||y|x^2 - |b|a^2\right| = \left||y|(x^2-a^2)+a^2(|y| - |b|)\right|\leq|y||x+a||x-a|+a^2\left||y|-|b|\right|\leq$$
$$\leq 2|x-a|+|y-b|$$
so this is even a stronger inequality that you wanted.

Comment: oh wow that was fast, thank you so much!

Comment: Please kindly to be more explicit in your answer. While it is correct, the last inequality is far from obvious and has the potential to create frustration. There is no end to the proof either. Please be so kind to reformulate your answer by addressing my concerns. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wait why did this question get removed? i mean its pretty specific but this really helped me out. And the last inequality is pretty obvious to anyone that asks himself this question. The first step was just what i was missing.